# how to insert date and time in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Im having trouble inserting a row in my table. Here is the insert statement and table creation. This is part of a uni assignment hence the simplicity, what am i doing wrong? Im using oracle SQL developer Version 3.0.04.'

The problem i am having is that it is only inserting the dd/mon/yy but not the time. How do i get it to insert the time as well?

```
INSERT INTO WORKON (STAFFNO,CAMPAIGNTITLE,DATETIME,HOURS)
VALUES ('102','Machanic Summer Savings',TO_DATE('22/April/2011 8:30:00AM','DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SSAM'),'3')
;

CREATE TABLE WorkOn
(
    StaffNo        NCHAR(4),
    CampaignTitle  VARCHAR(50),
    DateTime       DATE,
    Hours          VARCHAR(2)
)
;
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: This is making no sense, i enter just a time in the field to test if time is working and it outputs a date WTF? This is really weird i may not use a date field and just enter the time in, i realise this will result in issues manipulating the data but this is making no sense...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are doing everything right by using a to_date function and specifying the time. The time is there in the database. The trouble is just that when you select a column of DATE datatype from the database, the default format mask doesn't show the time. If you issue a

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/MON/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'`

or something similar including a time component, you will see that the time successfully made it into the database.

Comment: omg thank you, just one last issue, it sets the format for all date formatted columns resulting in time showing for columns where i only want the date showing. Is it possible to specify it for a particular table?

Comment: then you'll have to specify the date format mask in your select statement. Something like "select to_char(datetime,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime from workon".

Answer (score 70):

You can use

```
insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

...`(to_date('2011/04/22 08:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));`

Comment: hi it still does not work, it only inserts the date part and ignores the time. If i enter just a time then it just converts it to a date... MySQL makes more sense than oracle to me...

Comment: Are you positive that the field is a DateTime one?  It's sounding now like it's just a Date field.  Do this to see:  DESC WORKON

Answer (score 6):

Just use `TO_DATE()` function to convert string to `DATE`.

For Example:

```
create table Customer(
       CustId int primary key,
       CustName varchar(20),
       DOB date);

insert into Customer values(1,'Vishnu', TO_DATE('1994/12/16 12:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table Customer(
       CustId int primary key,
       CustName varchar(20),
       DOB date);

insert into Customer values(1,'kingle', TO_DATE('1994-12-16 12:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Your code works and inserts both the date and time components. The problem is that when you query the database it is only displaying the date component and not the time component. You need to change how you are displaying the date in the `SELECT` statement and not change the `INSERT` statement.

---

#### Storing Dates and Times

> The problem i am having is that it is only inserting the dd/mon/yy but not the time. How do i get it to insert the time as well?

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type composed of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** stores all 7 of those bytes and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

Therefore, when you use the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO WORKON (
  STAFFNO,
  CAMPAIGNTITLE,
  DATETIME,
  HOURS
) VALUES (
  '102',
  'Machanic Summer Savings',
  TO_DATE('22/April/2011 8:30:00AM','DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SSAM'),
  '3'
);
```

Then it does **STORE** both the date and time components in the database.

If you want to see the binary values then you can use the `DUMP` function:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(datetime) FROM workon;
```

| DUMP(DATETIME) |
| --- |
| Typ=12 Len=7: 120,111,4,22,9,31,1 |

Which shows that there are 7 bytes that all have values so both the date and time components have been **stored** in the database.

---

#### Alternative Methods of Storing Dates and Times

Your code works but there are several other methods that you can use:

1. You can improve your code so that it uses the format models relating to the data (i.e. `MONTH` not `MON`, `YYYY` not `YY` and `HH12` which is equivalent to `HH` but explicitly states in the format model that a 12-hour clock is being used) and explicitly set the language that you expect the string to be received in (otherwise your code could break if you keep passing the English month but a user changes their session to have, for example, the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=French`):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO WORKON (
     STAFFNO,
     CAMPAIGNTITLE,
     DATETIME,
     HOURS
   ) VALUES (
     '102',
     'Machanic Summer Savings',
     TO_DATE(
       '22/April/2011 8:30:00AM',
       'DD/MONTH/YYYY HH12:MI:SSAM',
       'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
     ),
     '3'
   );
   ```
2. You can use [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) and [`INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B) literals:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO WORKON (
     STAFFNO,
     CAMPAIGNTITLE,
     DATETIME,
     HOURS
   ) VALUES (
     '102',
     'Machanic Summer Savings',
     DATE '2011-04-22' + INTERVAL '08:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
     '3'
   );
   ```
3. You can use a `TIMESTAMP` literal (which the database will implicitly cast to a `DATE` to match the data-type of the column):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO WORKON (
     STAFFNO,
     CAMPAIGNTITLE,
     DATETIME,
     HOURS
   ) VALUES (
     '102',
     'Machanic Summer Savings',
     TIMESTAMP '2011-04-22 08:30:00',
     '3'
   );
   ```

---

#### Displaying Dates and Times

> How do i get it to insert the time as well?

It is inserting the time component of the date; your problem is slightly different in that the value is being **stored** but is not being **displayed** when you query the table.

When you do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM workon;
```

Then the database will send the client application that you are using to query the database (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Java, PHP, etc.) the `DATE` as a binary value and then it is up to the client application to choose how to **display** that binary value in a way that is meaningful to you, the user.

Some client applications will display the date and time components. Others, such as SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLCl, will use the database's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the default format to display dates; the [default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` depends on where you are in the world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) but the common theme of all the default format models that Oracle uses around the world is that they only display the year, month and day components of a `DATE` and not the time components. (You would have to ask Oracle why they chose those defaults rather than displaying everything.)

To solve the **display** problem, you can either:

1. Explicitly format the `DATE` using `TO_CHAR`

   ```sql
   SELECT staffno,
          campaigntitle,
          TO_CHAR(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS datetime,
          hours
   FROM   workon;
   ```
2. Change the preferences on your client application. Refer to the documentation for whichever client application you are using on how to do this; but for SQL Developer you can refer to the answers in the question [SQL Developer is returning only the date, not the time. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12628385/1509264).
3. If your client application uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as its default for displaying dates then you can change the session parameter:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
   ```

   And that will change the format model that the database uses to handle **ALL** implicit conversions from dates-to-strings and strings-to-dates and those client applications will also change how they format dates.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SFQ7eKzr)