# How to use current date in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view in the Oracle DB which has the field called Update_Date

[image]

I need to select all the fields from the view if the update_date is equal to yesterday's date (may be Current date -1). I tried

```
select * from ack where update_date = SYSDATE - 1
```

But it is not returning any data. I see yesterday's dates in the DB.

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 4):

You may not be seeing any data because `SYSDATE` and the `update_date` column have a time component (all `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types have this) but the IDE you are using is just choosing not to show it to you. To [change this behaviour in SQL Developer see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12628385/1509264).

This will use any indexes you have on the `update_date` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ack
WHERE  update_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    update_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE );
```

This will use a function-based index on `TRUNC( update_date)` but will not use an index on the `update_date` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ack
WHERE  TRUNC( update_date ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from ack where trunc(update_date) = trunc(SYSDATE - 1)
```

What you posted is how dates are presented they probably contain also part with hours and minutes and so on. `trunc` cuts precision to days. Please execute:

```
select to_char(update_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') update_date, sysdate - 1 as curr_date from ack;
```

You're comparing those values and they are not identical. That's why you get no results.

Answer (score -1):

I like 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' over 'SYSDATE'- both should do the same thing but readability goes a long way.

I would recommend casting your 'UPDATE_DATE' to a DATE (if it is in datetime) then use CAST and DATEADD to adjust 'now' to 'yesterday'.

```
WHERE 
    CAST( update_date AS DATE) = CAST( DATEADD(day,-1,current_timestamp) AS DATE)
```

EDIT: Please don't use (Date-1) it is sloppy code and can have unintended consequences when used as part of some functions.

Comment: In Oracle, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `CURRENT_DATE`, `SYSTIMESTAMP` and `SYSDATE` are **not** the same. `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a date / timestamp (respectively) data type reflecting the current date and time on the *client* (both have a time component, the timestamp also has fractional seconds). `SYSDATE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP`  returns a date / timestamp (respectively) data type reflecting the current date/time on the *server* (again, both have a time component). If the client and server are in different timezones then you will see a difference between the two.

Comment: `DATEADD()` is not a valid Oracle function and there is no such thing as a `DATETIME` data type; all `DATE`s have a time component. `SYSDATE - 1` is perfectly valid code in Oracle - if you want to explicitly define the interval then use `SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY`.

Comment: I understand the difference and in my experience client would be the correct value if they are different. That's for correcting me on 'DATEADD' - I use ADD_MONTHS and knew there wasn't an ADD_DAYS but I think its important to call out the 'DAY' interval, I've seen some weird output.