# Converting a string contain date and time using to_date function

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to use **to_date** function in oracle-sqldeveloper to convert a string
`May 1 2019 12:00` to **date** datatype? Does Date in SQL store time too,
or it only stores date?  I tried using the to_date function with some
format but it always removes the time part.
If the time is not possible in Date datatype what could be a good alternative?

Comment: This is a **display** problem with SQL Developer and not a storage problem with the Oracle database. You haven't given us the code you are using with `TO_DATE`; assuming you've followed the documentation then the issue is that SQL Developer is using its default formatting and hiding the time component of the date... which would make this a duplicate of [SQL Developer is returning only the date, not the time. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628385)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your date to a string with (assuming 24-hour values, which seems likely as you don't have an AM/PM marker):

```
to_date('May 1 2019 12:00', 'Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI', 'nls_date_language=English')
```

The format elements are [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A). I've included the optional third argument to `to_date()` because your month name has to be interpreted in English, regardless of your session settings.

> it always removes the time part

Oracle dates always have both date and time parts, even if the time is set to midnight. You're probably seeing the result of that query as '01-MAY-19'.

Dates don't have any intrinsic human-readable format; Oracle uses its own internal representation, which you generally don't need to worry about.

In most clients and IDEs the session [NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html) is used to display native dates as strings. For historic reasons that still defaults to DD-MON-YY, despite Y2K, during database creation. it can be changed at database level, and sessions will then inherit that. But each session can override it, e.g. by issuing:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

You can also explicitly convert a date value back to a string, and specify which format elements you want to include, via a `to_char()` call. Only do that when displaying a value - if you're storing dates or passing them around to functions, always do that as the proper date data type, not as strings. (If you *have* to pass them outside the database as strings, e.g. to a remote API, you'd usually want to use an ISO-8601 format).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=347ef534a32a3249248a58c30bd554bc) showing the default output, explicitly formatted as a string (again, for display only - do not store or manipulate dates as string), and with the session format modified.

In SQL Developer you can also go to Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS and change the 'Date format' there - that setting will then apply when you create new sessions, without having to issue `alter session` each time.

Comment: That's cool. So that means when I am inserting like `insert into table values(to_date('May 1 2019 10:00','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI')` the time does get inserted. I need to use `select to_char(date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi')` to see the time. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, or change the NLS/client settings so it shows the time elements for all date values. But as you don't have an AM/PM marker you should be using `HH24` - updated the answer to use that instead of `HH12`.