# adding date to table in sql

Tags: sql

Trying to add the date to table in SQL. The column is set to data type of date, I can add the date but not the time. The time is the important part for me. 
this is my code;

```
insert into tutpracs(GRPNO, CLASSLOCATION, CAPACITY, CLASSTIME)
VALUES('18', 'w7y', '30', TO_DATE('06/07/1961 10:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS'));
```

the code runs and has no errors but the time is left off and only the date is inserted into the table.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TO_DATE is product specific, but which one...?)

Comment: what is the datatype of "CLASSTIME", date or datetime?

Comment: I'm using oracle SQL developer, it's date. I couldn't find datetime only date or timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all that information, all you have to do is make the variable a date variable. The format is `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`. You don't need to try to create a new one. If it is important that other values in the column remain strings, then try using `HH:MM:SS`, rather than `HH:MI:SS`.

Hope this helps. ;)

Comment: when i change HH:MI:SS. to HH:MM:SS i get the error message "format code appears twice"

Comment: EDITED... Nevermind. I messed up. MI is the correct form.

Comment: now i'm left with "literal does not match format string"

Comment: Try leaving out the formating. If you put it in `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS` format, it _should_ read it anyway.
In your case it would look like `. . . TO_DATE('19611/06/07 10:30:00'));`

Comment: I still just get the message about the literals not matching the format

Comment: if it helps i actually only need the time and not the date at all

Comment: Are you sure there's no datetime datatype? SQL server should have it. (Realized that the format only works if it's assumed to be datetime)

Comment: Theres no datetime as far as i can tell. I just right click on the table and click edit to change the data type

Comment: Scratch that. I did some googling. Oracle does indeed have different data types than typical SQL servers. Try using the date datatype. Their date datatype is supposed to work for times as well.
( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847 )

Comment: Moving to a new location. Said location may or may not allow access to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry I haven't been able to help. I thought it was a simple fix in the beginning, haha. Anyway, if it doesn't, I'll be back later to offer new ideas. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable answers in the meantime.

Comment: no worries thanks so much for trying, I copied the example exactly from the link above and it says unrecognised date format. Strange!!

Comment: I think I found the problem. "when you select a column of DATE datatype from the database, the default format mask doesn't show the time" ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536628/how-to-insert-date-and-time-in-oracle ) That solution should work. If that works, this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)