# I'm trying to insert a date to an Oracle table but I keep getting "expected DATE got NUMBER." (XPages ExtLib)

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to insert a date to an Oracle table but I keep getting this error message, "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER."  Can anyone help?

```
var rptDate = getComponent("computedField3").getValue();
var JavaRptDate:java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(rptDate.getTime());
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Test_Table (REPORT_DATE) VALUES ("        
                   + JavaRptDate + ")";                                         
var insertResult = @JdbcExecuteQuery("oracle", insertQuery);
```

This is what is printed for the date:

```
05/13/2016 08:34:45 AM  HTTP JVM: REPORT_DATE: 5/13/16 8:34 AM
05/13/2016 08:34:45 AM  HTTP JVM: insertQuery: INSERT INTO Test_Table  (REPORT_DATE) VALUES (2016-05-13)
```

Comment: You did not enclose the date with quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used SQL and Oracle, but it looks like you need to use TO_DATE to convert it to a date and it may need to be a date/time. See [how to insert date and time in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536628/how-to-insert-date-and-time-in-oracle)

Comment: I will try the TO_DATE but I'm not sure how to do this either with XPages or ExtLib.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The format of the SQL query should be standard. XPages wouldn't change what you need to pass as the query.

Comment: This worked for me and the link that you provided above was very helpful.  Thank you for your help!