# ORA-00917 missing comma in Powershell

Tags: powershell, odp.net

I am trying to perform an insert to the Oracle database using Powershell script. This approach works fine for a select query but for insert it gives an error. I read lot of Stack Overflow posts and various other sites and tried various methods but none of them are working.

How can I debug this? I am no expert in Powershell. I am quite sure there is some issue with the SQL.

```
Add-Type -Path "P:\Home\Full Oracle\ora11g_x86\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

try
{

$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=**)(PORT=1552)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=**)));User Id=**;Password=**;"
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)

$sid = "0001"
$region = "CH"
$timestamp = "2017-04-20 14:14:00"
$dep = "17-04-2017"
$scenario = "A"
$milestone = "ASB_XREF_GLCC_LOAD_2ND_END_E"
$finishtime = "2017-04-18/11:11"

$sql = "INSERT INTO APP_PDM_MART.PDM_GEAR_KPI_REP_SNOW(ST_ID,PRIORITY,STATUS,ACTIVE,ACTIVITY_DUE,ADD_REPORTED_BY,BUSINESS_CRITICALITY) VALUES($sid,$region,$timestamp,$dep,$scenario,$milestone,$finishtime)"

$oraConn.Open()
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$oraConn)
$tx = $oraConn.BeginTransaction()
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like the server doesn't like the spaces in your variables. Wihout adding quotes to the variables it won't look like a connected string in the SQL Statement. Try defining your variables like this:

```
$sid = "`'0001`'"
$region = "`'CH`'"
$timestamp = "`'2017-04-20 14:14:00`'"
$dep = "`'17-04-2017`'"
$scenario = "`'A`'"
$milestone = "`'ASB_XREF_GLCC_LOAD_2ND_END_E`'"
$finishtime = "`'2017-04-18/11:11`'"
```

So for example **2017-04-20 14:14:00** will be **'2017-04-20 14:14:00'** in the INSERT statement and it will be clear for the server where to separate the values.

Keep in mind that this will handle all the variables as strings (I don't know the data types of your table columns).

Comment: thank you very much. This solved the issue. I think Oracle have to write a better error. I was struggling so much with this. Only after random testing I realized the issue is with the data that was being passed. Even though I was passing string somewhere it was auto casted incorrectly by explicitly adding below it worked.
`$finishtime = $Args[6]`
`$finishtime = "'$finishtime'"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see the connection string in the query. Where is the **$oraConn** getting created.

I am considering you do have the db details.

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database username"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database password"
$datasource = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter database TNS name"
$query = "INSERT INTO APP_PDM_MART.PDM_GEAR_KPI_REP_SNOW(ST_ID,PRIORITY,STATUS,ACTIVE,ACTIVITY_DUE,ADD_REPORTED_BY,BUSINESS_CRITICALITY) VALUES($sid,$region,$timestamp,$dep,$scenario,$milestone,$finishtime)"
$connectionString = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
$command=$connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText=$query
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()
<# 
while ($reader.Read()) {
$reader.GetString(1) + ', ' + $reader.GetString(0)
}
#>
$connection.Close()
```

You do not have to do the while part,  thats why I have commented out. 
Refer the blog for further thing: [Oracle Database Query From Powershell](https://onejourneymultipletechnologies.blogspot.in/search?q=oracle)

If still getting issue, then please post the error as well. 
As mentioned in the comment that you do not have access to 64 bit and you wish to only use **Oracle.DataAccess.dll**, then you can try like this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")
```

OR as mentioned in the comment,to use Add-Type:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
```

Then I believe you should be able to create the connection string like this:

```
 $con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(“User Id=username;Password=password;Data Source=localhost/db1”)
 $con.open()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ranadip, thanks for the comment. I am using below dll, I dont have managed access, I am using oracle 11g 32 bit, In my office I have access only to this DLL so, please advise if you are aware the syntax for this. ( I have edited the connection details in the main query )

Comment: Go through the link , there i have shown how to add the dll using add type. Do that, then use the above syntax

Comment: unfortunately, I am allowed only 32bit installation of Oracle and I have no privileges to install 64 bit version. Which is why I am bound only to use Oracledataaccess dll. Kindly advise if there is way through that

Comment: @ManjitGUllal: I have made and edit in the answer and showed you how to use add type  for loading the dll. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Printing out the final SQL query that is being executed I see this -

```
INSERT INTO APP_PDM_MART.PDM_GEAR_KPI_REP_SNOW (ST_ID, PRIORITY, STATUS, ACTIVE, ACTIVITY_DUE, ADD_REPORTED_BY, BUSINESS_CRITICALITY) 
VALUES(0001, CH, 2017-04-20 14:14:00, 17-04-2017, A, ASB_XREF_GLCC_LOAD_2ND_END_E, 2017-04-18/11:11)
```

You need to correctly insert the date time properties. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536628/how-to-insert-date-and-time-in-oracle).

Comment: Hi Divya, thanks for the comment. In my case I am entering all the data as text regardless of date time using the variables so I am not sure How I can use this