# More on extracting year from date - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a question about selecting year from a date.  This is in Oracle database 12c.

Given that `SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;` returns `02/06/2020`

These work proper and return current year of `2020` -

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM trunc(SYSDATE)) FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) FROM DUAL;
```

These do not work and give error -

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '02/06/2019') FROM DUAL;
```

Gives error: `ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('02/06/2019','YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Gives error: `ORA-01722: invalid number`

The same format is being passed with sysdate and hard coded date of 02/06/2019.  Why is it that one works and the other does not?

I know I could just `select 2019 from dual` but that is not the point or use case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract year from a string (which `'02/06/2019'` is). First convert it to date:

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date('02/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) year FROM DUAL;

      YEAR
----------
      2019

SQL>
```

Or, if you **know** that last 4 digits are valid year, then

```
SQL> select substr('02/06/2019', -4) year from dual;

YEAR
----
2019

SQL>
```

Comment: Same solution a different way.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It comes down to the data type being passed.  `sysdate` by default is a DATE field.  A hard date like '02/06/2020' by default is considered a string.

To get around that, just cast the string as a date.  All good.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(cast('6-feb-2019' as date),'YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This does not always work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=964fd47cd8e7e0ae2e212a138220bfb1). If you want to convert a string to a date then use `TO_DATE` with an explicit format model and don't rely on implicit conversions through session parameters.

Comment: What is the difference between ``to_date()``` and ```cast(xxx as date)```?

Comment: `TO_DATE` takes a string argument (and optional format model and NLS settings parameters) and converts it to a date data type. `CAST( string_value AS DATE )` will perform an implicit string-to-date conversion using the current session's NLS parameters. A user can change their own session parameters at **ANY** time so you should never rely on them and the default session values will [depend on the territory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) set when creating the database so you cannot rely on them being consistent in an international setting.