# Oracle NLS_TERRITORY overrides NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: php, oracle, date, session, nls-lang

When in PHP application I specify

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
```

the output data format is as expected 2020-01-31 21:21:47
But when I add

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';
```

NLS_DATE_FORMAT doesn't take effect, NLS_TERRITORY overrides it.
31.01.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nls_date_format` (amongst other settings) is derived from the `nls_territory`. So when you set the territory, the database also sets the date format to the default for this area:

```
select value from nls_session_parameters
where  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';

select value from nls_session_parameters
where  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD.MM.RR
```

So you need to set the date format *after* the territory:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
select value from nls_session_parameters
where  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

Or - better still - use an explicit format mask in your conversions:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';
select sysdate, to_char ( sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) from dual;

SYSDATE  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY
-------- -------------------
07.02.20 2020-02-07 09:25:35
```

Comment: To cross reference my later 'answer', don't execute three ALTER statements; just use a single statement to set all values.  This is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's [default date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting. So when you set the `NLS_TERRITORY` you are also telling Oracle to reset the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (and other similar parameters) to the defaults for the new territory.

From the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/NLS_TERRITORY.html#GUID-161ABCAF-6095-4991-929A-B991A3642782):

> ## 1.206 NLS_TERRITORY
>
> `NLS_TERRITORY` specifies the name of the territory whose conventions are to be followed for day and week numbering.
>
> ...
>
> This parameter also establishes the default date format, the default decimal character and group separator, and the default ISO and local currency symbols.
>
> For information on these settings, see "[`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html#GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F)", "[`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.html#GUID-11CC68FD-A719-4F79-A012-9EAFAE999960)", "[`NLS_CURRENCY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/NLS_CURRENCY.html#GUID-9740ED98-BFEF-4D8F-BD83-30F400E04557)", and "[`NLS_ISO_CURRENCY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/NLS_ISO_CURRENCY.html#GUID-E756941C-8B43-423C-9C31-9CB05D7A0D68)".

If you want to change the territory and the date language & format then you will need to change the territory first (which will implicitly change the values for the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, etc. to the territory's defaults) and then you can change the date language & format to override those default territory settings:

So:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';
```

should be:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you should combine the settings into a single `ALTER SESSION` statement:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'CIS' NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
```

This is particularly recommended if you are executing the statement from PHP (and not just via a PL/SQL block or logon trigger) since it reduces the number of round-trips between PHP and the database, and can have a significant performance benefit.

For discussion of using triggers, see p 304 of the free Oracle PDF [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

If you do need to execute the statement from PHP, and have other SQL commands that are executed at logon, wrap them all in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
begin
     execute immediate
       'alter session set nls_date_format = ''YYYY-MM-DD'' nls_language = AMERICAN';
     -- other SQL statements could be put here
end;
```

This can be executed with one `oci_parse()` call, so it only needs one round-trip.