# how to use substr function with to_date in sql?

Tags: sql, date, substring, oracle10g

query is :

```
select substr(to_date('01-02-2018','mm-dd-yyyy'),4,3) from dual;
```

output is :

```
JAN
```

can anyone explain how the output came ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `substr('01-02-2018',4,3)` and get rid of the date conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply a text function directly to something that's of DATE datatype, you force an implicit conversion of the date into a string. This conversion uses the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter to decide the format of the output string.

In effect,

```
substr(to_date('01-02-2018','mm-dd-yyyy'),4,3)
```

is the same as

```
substr(to_char(to_date('01-02-2018','mm-dd-yyyy'), <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>),4,3)
```

The usual default value (for English-language versions of the database) of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is `DD-MON-RR` - which it sounds like the value of your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is set to, which means your query is doing:

```
substr(to_char(to_date('01-02-2018','mm-dd-yyyy'), 'DD-MON-RR'),4,3)
```

Therefore, the `substr` is working on the string `02-JAN-18`, and the 3 characters starting from the 4th character is `JAN`.

Rather than use `substr` on a date, you would do better to use `to_char` instead, e.g.:

```
to_char(to_date('01-02-2018', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 'MON')
```

Comment: The [default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` so, for many countries of the world, your generalisation "The usual default value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter is `DD-MON-RR`" does not hold true.

Comment: I've clarified.