# Which is the index for a query substr on a date type?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Hi I'm trying to do a query to print the users which do an action on a specific month on ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER.

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO2 (
    CODIGO NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT USUARIO_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT NOM_USUARIO_NN NOT NULL,
    TELEFONO VARCHAR2(12),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE SACA (
    COD_USUARIO NUMBER(10),
    COD_EJEMPLAR NUMBER(10),
    FECHA_PRES DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    FECHA_DEV DATE,
    CONSTRAINT SACA_PK PRIMARY KEY (COD_USUARIO, COD_EJEMPLAR, FECHA_PRES),
    CONSTRAINT USUARIO_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_USUARIO) REFERENCES USUARIO2(CODIGO) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT EJEMPLAR_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_EJEMPLAR) REFERENCES EJEMPLAR(CODIGO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here are the values of SACA:

```
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (123,778899, '01-01-2017','02-05-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (123,112233, '01-01-2017','02-05-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (234,882143,'04-01-2017','04-07-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (234,777722,'04-01-2017','04-07-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (345,976543, '01-01-2017','02-05-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (456,446733,'04-01-2017','04-07-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (567,778899, '01-01-2017','02-05-2017');
INSERT INTO SACA VALUES (890,222266,'04-01-2017','04-07-2017');
```

And this is the query. i would like to query the users which get a book on a specific month (05) from column `FECHA_DEV`. So here is the query:

```
SELECT usuario2.nombre
FROM usuario2
JOIN saca ON usuario2.codigo=saca.cod_usuario WHERE SUBSTR(FECHA_DEV,3,5) IN ('05');
```

The query is empty, but if a change the values, and ask from the first and last position it works.

¿So which are the index of the month for the DATE format?

Comment: When it comes to date/time functions/operators the DBMS differ a lot. So it is important to know the DBMS you're using. [Edit] the question and add the tag please.

Comment: Possibly a candidate for a computed column? Depending on your load.

Comment: I try to do others queries, like print the day, or the year, from the position (0,2) to the date, and (7,9) for the year, and it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SUBSTR`, last parameter is for `length` from position defined with second parameter :

```
WHERE SUBSTR(FECHA_DEV, 3, 2) IN ('05'); -- changed 5 to 2
```

However, you can use `extract` :

```
WHERE extract(month FROM FECHA_DEV) = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming Oracle, because of the use of the `number` data type and the `sysdate` reference.

---

Don't use string functions on DATE values. It is going to fail at one point or the other (e.g. on my computer, `SUBSTR(sysdate,3,5)` returns `-MAR-` not `03`).

It's better to extract the month as a number.

So to get all rows where FECHA_DEV is in May, you should use:

```
SELECT usuario2.nombre
FROM usuario2
   JOIN saca ON usuario2.codigo=saca.cod_usuario 
WHERE extract(month from FECHA_DEV) = 5;
```

The above would require an index like this:

```
create index idx_fecha_dev_month on SACA  ( extract(month from FECHA_DEV)  );
```

Whether the index would be used is a different question. You will have to check the execution plan to verify it.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿So which are the index of the month for the DATE format?

The premise of the question is flawed as a `DATE` is formatless as it is stored internally as [7 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) (respectively: century, year-of-century, month, day-of-month, hour, minute and second) so there is no universal string representation of a `DATE` data type.

The [`SUBSTR( string, start_character, length )` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) takes:

- A string as a its first argument;
- The index starting character of the sub-string is the second argument and the first character in the string is at index 1 (and not 0); and
- The length of the returned sub-string as its third argument.

So the first errors are that, if you are assuming the format `DD-MM-RR` and want a 2-character long sub-string starting from the 4th character of the string then the 2nd and 3rd argument should be `4, 2` and not `3, 5`.

The first thing Oracle will do when you pass a `DATE` as the first argument is to try to implicitly convert the `DATE` to a string and your function call is effectively:

```sql
SUBSTR(
  TO_CHAR(
    fecha_dev,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  4,
  2
)
```

The [default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting so you will not get a consistent value between users in different parts of the world (i.e. in Spain the default is `DD/MM/RR` whereas in America it is `DD-MON-RR` and the month is displayed as characters and in Sweden it is `RRRR-MM-DD` and getting the 4th and 5th characters would give the last year digit and a hyphen).

Even if your users are all in the same territory there is no guarantee that they will not set their own session parameters as any user can issue a command to alter their session to change it. For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD HH24MISS MONRR';
```

*(and, yes, that date format does get used in some settings)*

So, you should never rely on implicit conversion of dates to strings as you cannot be certain that you will get a consistent format.

If you do want to use `SUBSTR` then you should explicitly convert the date to a string and specify the format model:

```sql
WHERE SUBSTR( TO_CHAR( fecha_dev, 'DD-MM-RR' ), 4, 2 ) IN ( '05' )
```

However, if you are going to do that then you can just skip the `SUBSTR` and just output the month:

```sql
WHERE TO_CHAR( fecha_dev, 'MM' ) = '05'
```

Or you can use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
WHERE EXTRACT( MONTH FROM fecha_dev ) = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want all records with `FECHA_DEV` in the month of May.

If you want May in all years, use

```
WHERE MONTH(FECHA_DEV) = 5
```

But that WHERE expression must evaluate the MONTH function for every row. So you may be able to use an index on that expression.

If you want records from May of a certain year use a range search.

```
WHERE FECHA_DEV >= '2017-05-01' AND FECHA_DEV < '2017-06-01'
```

Then an index on the DATEs in the FECHA_DEV column will help, as it will let the server do an index range scan.

**Pro tip** Try to avoid treating dates as character strings. SQL offers all sorts of cool date arithmetic you can use when you treat dates as DATE or DATETIME types.

To display DATE or DATETIME values, use [DATE_FORMAT().](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780)

Comment: Oracle does not have a `MONTH` function. `DATE_FORMAT` is an Oracle OLAP Data Manipulation Language function and does not exist in Oracle RDBMS. Also, if you want to use ranges then don't use strings; use date literals `WHERE FECHA_DEV >= DATE '2017-05-01' AND FECHA_DEV < DATE '2017-06-01'` [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=16cf847bc6c33cd08868f204854ff77a)

Answer (score 0):

`FECHA_DEV` is a date column and you should not treat it like a string.
Use [`EXTRACT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) to get the month:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM FECHA_DEV) = 5
```

Comment: Yees, It's woks on that way. Thank you.