# Oracle SQL Query TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, oracle12c

I have a question regarding the following query in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('10-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

When I run it the result is the following `10-NOV-15`. From what I read in the Oracle docs the YYYY should convert to a 4-digit year but it converts into 2-digit year. Why is this happening?

Comment: It isn't.  The value is just being printed that way.

Comment: The function `to_date` converts STRING to DATE. And then Oracle is converting this date back to string using default format of your session: `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters where PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'` which most likely is `DD-MON-YY`.

Comment: Storage and display format are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

The date is being set with a 4-digit year.

However, you are being shown the date using the default format that Oracle is currently using to display dates in your user's session. The [default format Oracle uses for implicit date conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) depends on the territory. For America (among others) this is `DD-MON-RR` and will have a 2-digit year; but for Sweden the default is `RRRR-MM-DD` and a 4-digit year will be displayed.

This format can be set using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';
```

So, if instead you set the default format to `YYYY-MM-DD` (the ISO-8601 date format) using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Then your query:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('10-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Would output `2015-11-10`.

If you want a specific format for a date then you should not rely on implicit conversions as **ANY** user can set their own format at **ANY** time and you will not get consistent outputs; instead you should use an explicit conversion:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('10-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Would output `10-11-2015`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that this isn't happening by using `extract()`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM TO_DATE('10-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ) FROM DUAL;
```

The two digit year is only how the value is being presented.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of using below can be better:

SELECT TO_DATE('10-11-2015','DD-MM-RRRR') FROM DUAL;

Comment: Better how? It will produce the same result. The `RR` and `RRRR` format masks were a band-aid to deal with Y2K issues, but they just moved the problem to the middle of the century, which in a few more years will be closer than the start of it. A [standard date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) is the safest format.