# SQL Unable to filter for a specific date with Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, where-clause

This might be something simple but I cannot get the desired output.

I am using this simple query below to get the latest `exp_date` of an `item_no`

```
select g.item_no,max(g.exp_date)
from grn_drug_item g
group by g.item_no
```

1st query only displays following result for `01-AUG-20`

```
IT00002530 01-AUG-20
```

Now I want to filter above results for a 'specific' latest `exp_date` (ex: `01-AUG-20` as above) so I modified the query to:

```
select g.item_no,max(g.exp_date)
from grn_drug_item g
where g.exp_date = to_date('01-AUG-20','DD-MON-YY')
group by g.item_no
```

But this gives me multiple rows and if I use `where g.item_no = 'IT00002530'` it fetches the desired output.

How can I get the filtering working for a specific `exp_date` here?

Comment: Use [`HAVING MAX(g.exp_date) = @my_max_date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2):

Without access to your data this is slightly speculative, but it looks like you're picking up items which have a later `exp_date`. Your filter is too early - those items with later dates *and* that specific date will be included in the filter, and the maximum date within that subset is obviously that same date.

You can apply a filter after grouping with `having`:

```
select g.item_no,max(g.exp_date)
from grn_drug_item g
group by g.item_no
having max(g.exp_date) = to_date('01-AUG-20','DD-MON-YY')
```

The use of 'YY' is slightly worrying; using two-digit year at all is a problem, but if you must, then use `RR`. It's better to use 4-digit years though, and for a fixed date it's simpler to use a date literal:

```
having max(g.exp_date) = date '2020-08-01'
```

Comment: Thank you very much and for the suggestion! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The where clause is executed before the GROUP BY so you don't get items with a highest exp_date = 1/8/2020 but you get items with at least one exp_date = 1/8/2020.

To apply the filtering on the result after the group by, you need to use HAVING:

```
select g.item_no,max(g.exp_date) as max_exp_date
from grn_drug_item g
group by g.item_no
having max_exp_date = to_date('01-AUG-20','DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: You should use the aggregation itself in the `HAVING` clause, rather than the field alias.

Comment: think there's a typo in having clause? thank you anyway :)

Comment: I like to use the alias for readability but apparently support of it depends on database product. So it may be better indeed to repeat the `max(g.exp_date)` as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your use of the `WHERE` clause. Your query currently selects all items that has one instance of expiry on the 1st of August, but can have multiple expiry dates.

Using `HAVING MAX(g.exp_date) = to_date('01-AUG-20','DD-MON-YY')` should get you what you want, as it identifies the **latest** expiry date for each item. Your query should look like this:

```
select g.item_no, max(g.exp_date)
from grn_drug_item g
group by g.item_no
having max(g.exp_date) = to_date('01-AUG-20','DD-MON-YY')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@AlexPoole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63409963/1945782), you may also want to consider turning your simple script into a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15).

This will allow you to utilise variable dates in the call.  For instance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getItemNumbersByMaxDate
    @maxDate AS DATE --  Assuming SQL can utilise DATE type
AS
    SELECT   g.item_no,max(g.exp_date)
    FROM     grn_drug_item g
    GROUP BY g.item_no
    HAVING   MAX(g.exp_date) >= @maxDate
```

Please note that I've written this for T-SQL, you may need to adjust it for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation on the other answers.  But you might find that filtering *before* the aggregation is a significant win on performance:

```
select g.item_no, max(g.exp_date)
from grn_drug_item g
where g.exp_date >= date '2020-08-01'
group by g.item_no
having max(g.exp_date) = date '2020-08-01';
```

This may significantly reduce the amount of data that needs to be aggregated.  Also note the use of `date` to introduce the date constant.

Comment: Great, never thought of that. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - Filter on date after grouping using the `HAVING` clause and you may also need to filter on a 24-hour range rather than a single date (if your dates have a non-midnight time component that is not being displayed by the user-interface you are using).

---

Lets assume that you have sample data that is something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE grn_drug_item ( item_no, exp_date ) AS
SELECT 'IT00002530', DATE '2020-08-01' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IT00002530', DATE '2020-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANOTHER001', DATE '2020-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANOTHER001', DATE '2020-08-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTHER00002', DATE '2020-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTHER00002', DATE '2020-08-04' FROM DUAL;
```

And your [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is set to the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format/50164234#50164234) for America/China/UK of `DD-MON-RR`.

Then if you use your query:

```sql
SELECT g.item_no,
       MAX(g.exp_date)
FROM   grn_drug_item g
GROUP BY g.item_no
```

You will get the output:

> ```
> ITEM_NO    | MAX(G.EXP_DATE)
> :--------- | :--------------
> ANOTHER001 | 05-AUG-20      
> OTHER00002 | 04-AUG-20      
> IT00002530 | 01-AUG-20
> ```

Which matches your statement of:

> 1st query only displays following result for 01-AUG-20
>
> ```
>  IT00002530 01-AUG-20
> ```

If we run the query:

```sql
SELECT g.item_no,
       MAX(g.exp_date)
FROM   grn_drug_item g
WHERE  g.exp_date = DATE '2020-08-01'
GROUP BY g.item_no
```

Then we are filtering the rows before grouping and will get the maximum from the filtered rows; which outputs:

> ```
> ITEM_NO    | MAX(G.EXP_DATE)    
> :--------- | :------------------
> ANOTHER001 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00
> ```

*(The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is now set to the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS` to display the time component as well)*

This only shows the rows `ITEM_NO` that have a row where the `EXP_DATE` is exactly `2020-08-01T00:00:00`. Since the sample data for `IT00002530` has a time component of `12:00:00` it is not showing in the results.

To replicate your results I would need to filter on a 24 hour period and not a single instance at midnight:

```sql
SELECT g.item_no,max(g.exp_date)
FROM   grn_drug_item g
WHERE  g.exp_date >= DATE '2020-08-01'
AND    g.exp_date <  DATE '2020-08-01' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY g.item_no
```

Which would output:

> ```
> ITEM_NO    | MAX(G.EXP_DATE)    
> :--------- | :------------------
> ANOTHER001 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00
> IT00002530 | 2020-08-01T12:00:00
> ```

But you appear to want the rows where the maximum is on the day `01-AUG-20` so you would need to calculate the maximum and then filter on that; which you can do using a `HAVING` clause rather than a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT g.item_no,
       MAX(g.exp_date)
FROM   grn_drug_item g
GROUP BY g.item_no
HAVING MAX(g.exp_date) >= DATE '2020-08-01'
AND    MAX(g.exp_date) <  DATE '2020-08-01' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

*(Again, if your dates have a time component that is not always set to midnight then you want to filter on a 24 hour range rather than on a single instant.)*

Which outputs:

> ```
> ITEM_NO    | MAX(G.EXP_DATE)    
> :--------- | :------------------
> IT00002530 | 2020-08-01T12:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bcabeaeff93fde26b22e98b3317cb0ff)*