# How to display month in different formats

Tags: sql, oracle

When i perform this query

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

I get current date with month in shortcut format (NOV). How can i get the same result but getting month in full format(NOVEMBER) and in numerical value

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263759/oracle-date-format-while-using-to-char

Comment: [The Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) is a good place to start. I realise it helps if you know where to look in the docs, but there are [more general topics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C) that can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are built in formatting options in MSSQL, and assume there are in Oracle.  A quick google gave me this website that shows how:

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-date/

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
FROM
  dual;
```

Comment: I still cant find how to display it like numeric value

Comment: what is the specific format you want?  2022-12-31

Comment: yes. this format

Comment: Edited answer with correct format