# Is it possible to create a function that auto converts SQL values from date to string?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example with the following query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, TO_CHAR(birthday, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as birthday FROM master
```

Is there some way I can forgo the TO_CHAR declaration and have the database auto convert the values for me? I've been trying to find a dynamic solution such that it autoconverts any value that's in a DATE column in every table, but to no avail.

Ideally I would like to just run the following query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, birthday FROM master
```

To get all values in their desired format. Is it also possible to do the vice versa from:

```
INSERT INTO master (first_name, last_name, birthday) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, TO_DATE(:birthday, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO master (first_name, last_name, birthday) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :birthday)
```

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/14853083

Comment: `MM/DD/YYYY` is not a good format to store as searching and comparisons are complicated.  Use `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - given the OP, it's obvious the column is a DATE, not a CHAR or VARCHAR.  So it is _not_ being stored in 'MM/DD/YYYY' or any other character format.  He's wanting to know how to convert _from_ that string format _to_ the DATE type, without having to use TO_CHAR or  TO_DATE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start with a date but Oracle needs it as a string (for example for displaying the output!) you either use `TO_CHAR`, with or without a format model (and a few other parameters as needed), or you don't use anything and Oracle calls `TO_CHAR` for you implicitly, with default values for the parameters. The most important, of course, is the date format model. This is a session parameter called `nls_date_format`; to see **all** your nls settings, you can run

```
select * from v$nls_parameters;
```

Conversely, if you start with a string but Oracle needs a date (to insert in a column of date data type, for example, or to use in some date computation, etc.), either you use `TO_DATE`, with or without a date format model, or Oracle calls it for you - again with the defaults, including `nls_date_format`.

Note that some (but not all) front-ends ignore your `nls_date_format` and use a setting you find in the user interface. Dumb feature if you ask me, but you just need to know about it.

Also note that `timestamp` and `date` are different, and they use different `nls` parameters for default formatting. And the same with `timestamp with time zone`. So if something doesn't seem right, consider the data types carefully.

On my system:

```
select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';


VALUE                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
dd-MON-yyyy

select sysdate from dual;   -- I didn't use `to_char` so Oracle did

SYSDATE    
-----------
12-MAR-2021

create table t (dt date);

insert into t (dt) values ('12-OCT-2020');  -- BAD PRACTICE!

select * from t;

DT         
-----------
12-OCT-2020
```

Now, be aware that the implicit conversion posse hunts down developers who abuse implicit conversions. Now that you know how it's done, don't ever do it anywhere that matters (for example in production). It's OK for quickly building up a test case while you are developing a query; exceptionally poor practice in general. Use `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` as needed and you'll be fine!

Comment: you beat me to it.  A very good explanation that pretty well explained it all.

Comment: See also: [Oracle's default DATE format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264). The default varies depending on which territory is set on your database; so you should **NEVER** rely on implicit conversions when you are working in an international setting as users in different countries are likely to have different default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` values.

Answer (score -3):

To overcome all the headach of conversion of datatypes in your database try to change your date data type to timestamp and when you fetch it in your app try to convert it to date using date() function.

Comment: The OP's question is about getting the database to do the work. Suggesting they do the work in their application is wide of the mark.

Comment: I downvote because it is bad advice.  Telling the OP he should change his DATE column to a timestamp "to  overcome all the headach of conversion of datatypes ", then have to convert to DATE in the app?  With the additional conversion to/from strings?  Seriously?