# Convert a number to yyyy-mm-dd format SQL

Tags: sql, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column like this 120081212. the format of the column is Number.

I used:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(SUBSTRING(My_Column,2,6)) ,'yymmdd')
FROM My_Table
```

The output is: 2008-12-12 00:00:00.000. But I want just `2008-12-12`.

The format of the output is not important.

Comment: Documentation for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm. Also, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those components. It **NEVER** stores any formatting information.

Therefore, if you want a `DATE` to have a particular format then you need to convert it to another data-type (i.e. a string) that can store the formatted value:

```sql
SELECT my_column,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           SUBSTR(My_Column,2,8),
           'yyyymmdd'
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       ) AS formatted_value
FROM   My_Table;
```

*(Note: you want `SUBSTR` rather than `SUBSTRING` and you want to take 8 characters and not 6.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE My_Table (My_Column) AS
SELECT '120081212' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MY_COLUMN | FORMATTED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 120081212 | 2008-12-12 |

---

If you do want it as a `DATE` then remove the `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT my_column,
       TO_DATE(
         SUBSTR(My_Column,2,8),
         'yyyymmdd'
       ) AS date_value
FROM   My_Table;
```

However, you will then be relying on whatever user interface you are using to format the date to a human readable format. In SQL/Plus and SQL Developer, this is based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and [the default format is dependent on your territory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1c2afb060464f3b513478c490f182603)*