# Date format in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

How to check the date format for a specific column in a table in oracle?
Does oracle DATE datatype have the ability to store both formats (US and european)? and if so, is there a way to distinguish which one is the month and which is the date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing each of

1. century;
2. year-of-century;
3. month;
4. day;
5. hour;
6. minute; and
7. second

It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular format.

---

> How to check the date format for a specific column in a table in oracle?

It does not have any format so you cannot.

If you want to see the binary values of a `DATE` you can use the `DUMP` function:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(date_column) FROM table_name;
```

> Does oracle `DATE` datatype have the ability to store both formats (US and european)?

No, it never stores any format.

If you want to store formatted data then use a string data-type; however, this is generally considered to be bad practice for dates as it introduces ambiguity between days and months if you use both `DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY`. Best practice would be to store dates as a `DATE` and then pick the appropriate format when you **DISPLAY** the date.

---

If you want to **DISPLAY** a `DATE` date type then you can use the `TO_CHAR` function and specify the format model appropriate to the territory you want to display it as.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS eu_format,
       TO_CHAR(date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS us_format,
       TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS iso8601_format
FROM   table_name
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=088e7fe11591276700103d5518a1b0e3)*

The default format model (as used by the SQL engine when implicitly converting strings-to-dates, and vice-versa, or used by some client applications to **DISPLAY** a date) for different territories is listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dates are stored in an internal binary data format. Display formatting is handled by the client and is not stored.

This is the same as for numbers, for example, where the same value can be displayed as 1000, 1,000.00, 1e3 etc depending on the format mask used with the `to_char` function.