# Display the tenant name, and property address for all leases where the tenancy start date is between 1st January 2010 and 1st January 2015 inclusive

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex

SELECT LEASE_NO
FROM LEASE
WHERE STDATE >= 2010-01-01
AND ENDDATE <= 2015-01-01;

GAVE ME THIS ERROR ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATE` literals:

```sql
SELECT LEASE_NO
FROM   LEASE
WHERE  STDATE  >= DATE '2010-01-01'
AND    ENDDATE <= DATE '2015-01-01';
```

or use `TO_DATE` with string literals and an explicit format model:

```sql
SELECT LEASE_NO
FROM   LEASE
WHERE  STDATE  >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND    ENDDATE <= TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

---

Your code does not work as `2010-01-01` is parsed as the number `2010` and then subtract the number `01` (which simplifies to `1`) and then subtract another number `01` (which, again, simplifies to `1`) so your SQL statement is effectively:

```sql
SELECT LEASE_NO
FROM   LEASE
WHERE  STDATE >= 2008
AND    ENDDATE <= 2013;
```

You cannot compare a date to a number which is why you get the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

---

Note:

Do not just "Put single quotes round your date values." as this would change them to strings and not to dates and then you would be relying on an implicit string-to-date conversion that will depend on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and you are likely (with the [default NLS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264)) to get an error.

For example:

```sql
SELECT LEASE_NO
FROM   LEASE
WHERE  STDATE >= '2010-01-01'
AND    ENDDATE <= '2015-01-01';
```

With the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of `DD-MON-RR`, gives the error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=25e4fdf2dd9f55286a4a1e097659b44e)*