# Column to update the sysdate/time in PST

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have two columns (Status & Updated Date) in IG. Everytime the status column is change with something, I want to log the time it is updated (in PST). Here is how I'm doing it but its not working as expected.

I have created a dynamic action on my updated date column to set the value when it is changed. However, my updated column shows some incorrect time/date.

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(NEW_TIME( TO_DATE( CAST(SYSDATE as DATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ),  'GMT', 'PST' ), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') TIME_IN_PST
FROM
  TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzmor.png)

Comment: If this is a new application, I'd look at using a different datatype. With the datatype ```TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE``` the data is stored as a UTC date internally but at runtime it's displayed in the timezone of the user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSDATE` is already a date so you do not need to use `CAST` on it. Similarly, since it is already a date you do not need to use `TO_DATE` on it and this is likely to cause errors.

So your code can just be:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PST' ), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         AS TIME_IN_PST
FROM   DUAL;
```

However, you can make it even simpler using `SYSTIMESTAMP` (which returns a `TIMESTAMP` data type) and then you do not need to use the `NEW_TIME` function:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'PST', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         AS TIME_IN_PST
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which both output:

> | TIME_IN_PST |
> | --- |
> | 03-03-2022 08:03:27 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=348374e5870b8891e902612e93e39730)*

---

As for what is causing your code to be incorrect:

The `TO_DATE` function takes a string as the first argument. When you do:

```sql
TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Then Oracle will implicitly convert it to:

```sql
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    SYSDATE,
    ( SELECT value
      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
      WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
  ),
  'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
)
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is not `MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` (and the [default NLS date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) never matches that) then you will get either an error or, worse, an unexpected and probably invalid result.

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-RR';

SELECT TO_CHAR(
         NEW_TIME(
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ),
           'GMT',
           'PST'
         ),
         'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS TIME_IN_PST
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TIME_IN_PST |
> | --- |
> | 03-02-0022 16:00:00 |

Which has the wrong time component **AND** the wrong century!

To solve this, do not use `TO_DATE` on values that are already `DATE`s.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=05f77451da9a7db434594f67918ddd4f)*

Comment: When I tried the code, the timestamp is accurate in PST, however the date is always appearing as "03-02-2022"

Comment: Any other thoughts on the date?

Comment: @VamC [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71339973/edit) your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for the sample data; the `SELECT` statement you are using to display the data; your current NLS session parameters for dates/timestamps; and the expected output. Without knowing what you are putting in, what you expect out and what your session parameters are its difficult to determine.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot of my apex view - Under dynamic actions, you'll see the code I'm using. Currently it returns the accurate PST time though, however the date is incorrect.