# SQL- missing comma in insert statement line

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(
    supplier_ID      NUMBER not null,
    supplier_Name    varchar2 (50) not null,
    supplier_Addr    varchar2 (100),
    supplier_Town    varchar2 (30),
    supplier_State   varchar2 (30),
    supplier_Pcode   varchar2 (15) not null,
    supplier_Phone1  varchar2 (15),
    supplier_Phone2  varchar2 (15),
    supplier_Contact varchar2 (50),
    supplier_Fax     varchar2 (15),
    supplier_Email   varchar2 (40),
    supplier_Renew   DATE,
    supplier_Creditlimit NUMBER,
    supplier_Comments varchar2 (500),
    PRIMARY KEY (supplier_ID)
);

INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_ID, supplier_Name, supplier_Addr, supplier_Town, supplier_State, supplier_Pcode, supplier_Phone1, supplier_Phone2, supplier_Contact, supplier_Fax, supplier_Email, supplier_Renew, supplier_Creditlimit,supplier_Comments)
VALUES (010203, 'DSHK COMPANY', 'G 7 JLN TUNKU HASSAN ', 'Seremban', 'Negeri Sembilan', 70000, 604-42449268, 09-4265050, 'DSHK CO', 04-2224568, 'DSHKCOMPANY@GMAIL.COM', 2024-08-23, 1000, 'COMPANY WILL CALL BEFORE SENDING THE GOODS');
```

I keep getting missing comma error for insert statement. Please guide me, tq

Comment: That's because you are not quoting all your string literals. And note that the number 010203 is no different from 10203.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the phone numbers into strings as you have defined them as varchar.

```
70000,604-42449268,09-4265050
```

->

```
'70000', '604-42449268', '09-4265050'
```

I think you need to do tha same for date... that is 2024-08-23 -> '2024-08-23'

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the create statement: `NUMBER` is not a valid type. You can use e.g. `int(11) unsigned`.

Also, instead of `varchara(500)` you can use `text`. So the create statement should be:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(
    supplier_ID int(11) not null, 
    supplier_Name varchar (50) not null, 
    supplier_Addr varchar (100), 
    supplier_Town varchar (30), 
    supplier_State varchar (30), 
    supplier_Pcode varchar (15) not null, 
    supplier_Phone1 varchar (15), 
    supplier_Phone2 varchar (15), 
    supplier_Contact varchar (50), 
    supplier_Fax varchar (15), 
    supplier_Email varchar (40), 
    supplier_Renew DATE, 
    supplier_Creditlimit int(11), 
    supplier_Comments text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (supplier_ID) 
);
```

For your insert statement you must enclose all non-numerical values in quotes, like this:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_ID, supplier_Name, supplier_Addr, supplier_Town, supplier_State, supplier_Pcode, supplier_Phone1, supplier_Phone2, supplier_Contact, supplier_Fax, supplier_Email, supplier_Renew, supplier_Creditlimit,supplier_Comments) 
VALUES (010203, 'DSHK COMPANY', 'G 7 JLN TUNKU HASSAN ', 'Seremban', 'Negeri Sembilan', 70000, '604-42449268', '09-4265050', 'DSHK CO', '04-2224568', 'DSHKCOMPANY@GMAIL.COM', '2024-08-23', 1000, 'COMPANY WILL CALL BEFORE SENDING THE GOODS');
```

Comment: `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR2` are valid data types in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using an Oracle database since you are using `VARCHAR2` data types then use string and date literals for `VARCHAR2` and `DATE` data types respectively:

```sql
insert into suppliers (
  supplier_ID,
  supplier_Name,
  supplier_Addr,
  supplier_Town,
  supplier_State,
  supplier_Pcode,
  supplier_Phone1,
  supplier_Phone2,
  supplier_Contact,
  supplier_Fax,
  supplier_Email,
  supplier_Renew,
  supplier_Creditlimit,
  supplier_Comments
) values (
  010203,
  'DSHK COMPANY',
  'G 7 JLN TUNKU HASSAN ',
  'Seremban',
  'Negeri Sembilan',
  '70000',
  '604-42449268',
  '09-4265050',
  'DSHK CO',
  '04-2224568',
  'DSHKCOMPANY@GMAIL.COM',
  DATE '2024-08-23',
  1000,
  'COMPANY WILL CALL BEFORE SENDING THE GOODS'
);
```

If you don't then, for example, `604-42449268` will be parsed as 604 subtract 42449268 which gives the result `−42448664`.

Do not use a string literal such as `'2024-08-23'` for the date as Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string literal to a date using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session paramter. The [default Oracle `DATE` format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format/50164234#50164234) depends on the territory you are in and for most territories that implicit conversion will fail. Either use a `DATE` literal or explicitly call `TO_DATE('2024-08-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` with a format model.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=961a0c110a0ce355bdafaab30a2fd6fd)*