# How do I correctly input Date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01843

I created a table with parameters:

```
GUIDE_NUM   NOT NULL CHAR(4)  
LAST_NAME            CHAR(15) 
FIRST_NAME           CHAR(15) 
ADDRESS              CHAR(25) 
CITY                 CHAR(25) 
STATE                CHAR(2)  
POSTAL_CODE          CHAR(5)  
PHONE_NUM            CHAR(12) 
HIRE_DATE            DATE
```

But when I try to insert values into the table for example:

```
INSERT INTO GUIDE VALUES('AM01' ,'Abrams', 'Miles', '54 Quest Ave.','Williamsburg','MA', '01096','617-555-6032','6-3-2012');
```

There seems to be a problem with the `DATE` syntax because Oracle keeps displaying:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

and I even tried inputing different date formats like `'06-03-2012'` and it keeps displaying the same error.

Comment: just use `date'2012-03-06'` instead(presumably month is march(03))

Comment: Check the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format It has all the info you need to know.

Comment: `'06-03-2012'` may look like a date but it is a string literal. Use a date literal: `DATE '2012-03-06'` or a timestamp literal: `TIMESTAMP '2012-03-06 00:00:00'` or use `TO_DATE('06-03-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` to convert the string literal to a date.

Comment: As a side observation, all of your character columns are defined as CHAR(n).  This is a fixed-length format.  So if someone's first name is 'Joe', it will still be 15 characters long - "Joe" and right padded with 12 spaces.  What a waste of storage!  And when searching, 'Joe' != 'Joe            '.  Much better to use VARCHAR2(n), where 'n' is a reasonable estimate of the max length needed.

Comment: I suggest familiarising yourself with the [syntax page for literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html). And as @EdStevens said, [avoid `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471).