# SQL "TO_DATE" fuction seems weird

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date

Quick question about the function "TO_DATE" in SQL_DEVELOPER who looks weird.

I need to do an SQL query to make an dashboard after and for that, I need to change date to be more understandier for other people.

So i've got a column called:

DT_EXP_C (EXPIRATION DATE) | CHAR (8 BYTE)

So I try this:

```
SELECT

dt_exp_c AS DATE_TEST -- RAW DATA,

TO_DATE (dt_exp_c, 'YYYYMMDD') AS EXPIRATION_DATE -- WORKED DATA

FROM et_co
```

The return of this query is:

| DATE_TEST | EXPIRATION_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 20470130 | 30/01/47 |
| 20480810 | 10/08/48 |
| ... | ... |

The problem is, I want 'YYYY' to be for example '2048' but even if i put 'YYYY' in the code, the code return only the two last figures... ( '48' instead of '2048')

If you could help me to resolve this thing, it would be really nice!

While waiting to your answer i'll keep looking for a solution by myself :)

Good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

In the client application, SQL Developer, the client will receive the unformatted binary `DATE` from the database and will try to **display** it to you, the user, in a meaningful way. The default method is to convert the date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter; so what you are seeing is not a date but the client application's string representation of the date for display purposes.

In this case, the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for your territory is set to `DD/MM/RR` (see [Oracle's default date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264)).

If you want to change it then either set the preferences in SQL Developer (which will set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameters for this session and then automatically when you log into each subsequent session) or use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

*(or whatever format you want the dates to be displayed as.)*

To set the format in your current session.

---

> I need to do an SQL query to make an dashboard after and for that, I need to change date to be more understandier for other people.

Then do not rely on implicit formatting of dates, convert the date back to a string with your desired formatting model:

```sql
SELECT dt_exp_c AS DATE_TEST,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE (dt_exp_c, 'YYYYMMDD'),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'         -- Or whatever format model you require
       ) AS EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM et_co
```

If you do not provide an explicit format then the method of displaying the binary `DATE` value is left up to the whims of whatever client application you use to connect to the database.

Comment: @Onyx My advice would be to set the NLS format to something that displays date **and** time (since a `DATE` data type always contains both and that way you can see the entire value) and if you want a specific format in your output for display purposes then use `TO_CHAR` to get the desired format.