# What is missing to get Oracle SELECT DATE type (DD-MON-YY) field ORDER BY field DESC to sorts on YY and not DD?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Been trying to figure out why the sorting is being done by the DD of the value which is in the format of DD-MON-YY and not on the YY.

```
SELECT MY_DATE 
FROM MY_DB 
ORDER BY MY_DATE DESC;
```

Originally I had some TO_CHAR and TO_DATE functions in this but now it is as basic as it can be and yet it is still not sorting as I would expect it to.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for that behaviour

Comment: Would using iso date format YYYY-MM-DD work in your case?

Comment: @Peter206 I'm not sure if you mean for me to change the dates already stored. The format of the existing data is in the format of DD-MON-YY.

Comment: Oracle accepts the date format as you write it. But it also accepts ISO date format. See for instance here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format - often it is a good idea (avoiding ambiguity) to explicitely state the used format in the TO_CHAR and TO_DATE functions

Comment: @nbk Took me a bit to find what you were talking about with fiddle. I made a test there but it operates differently than our DB on our network. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/461489/6

Comment: Dates are not stored in a specific format.  Formatting is for display purposes.

Comment: @edjm you have posted only a table buit with no data, so we can't say how you want the data sorted

Comment: The behavior you describe would only make sense if your "date" was in fact stored as a string and not as a `date` data type. If it is stored as a string (i.e. `varchar2` or some such) you can't sort it directly as a `date`; you'd have to convert it to a `date` datatype with the `to_date` function and sort that.

Comment: @pmdba according to the SQL script and what it shows me in the SQLDeveloper it is a DATE type.

Comment: @edjm Then as noted above it should always sort according to its binary date value and not according to its display format. Display format (i.e. DD-MON-YY) should be irrelevant.

Comment: @pmdba I still have no idea why this is not displaying in the correct order but I have to move on to other things at this time. Thank you all for providing some input.