# Oracle SQL Timestamp error while selecting from timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query:

```
select
timestamp_column
from my_table
```

Based on:

```
create table my_table (
timestamp_column timestamp
)

insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('11-JUL-23 09.54.22.389941 AM')

insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('19-OCT-23 02.27.43.184645 PM')

insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('03-OCT-23 11.42.29.618354 AM')

insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('22-AUG-23 04.32.15.526578 PM')

insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('14-AUG-23 04.07.50.805201 PM')
```

I'm getting this error when doing the select:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Have no idea why, have converted them to_char(timestamp_column) AS ABC
and it keeps happening.
Any idea why?

Comment: When inserting those values, how would you know if it's 1823 vs 2023? Try reformatting your timestamp. The problem is not with the select statement, but rather, the insert statement.

Comment: Keep timestamps as timestamps. don't use to_char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, a `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type composed of 7-13 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second and between 0 and 9 digits of fractional seconds (stored in 0-6 bytes).

When you use:

```sql
insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values('11-JUL-23 09.54.22.389941 AM')
```

You are inserting a string literal and not a timestamp.

Oracle will try to be helpful and perform an implicit cast from a string to a timestamp and will convert your query to:

```sql
insert into my_table (timestamp_column
) values (
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '11-JUL-23 09.54.22.389941 AM',
    (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT')
  )
)
```

If the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter does not match the format you are using then you will get an exception.

What you should do is **NEVER** rely on implicit casts. Instead, either:

1. Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO my_table (timestamp_column)
   VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2023-07-11 09:54:22.389941')
   ```
2. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO my_table (timestamp_column)
   VALUES (
     TO_TIMESTAMP(
       '11-JUL-23 09.54.22.389941 AM',
       'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM',
       'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
     )
   )
   ```

   *Note: if you are going to be using language specific strings then you should also explicitly specify the language of the date.*
3. Don't use this option. You could alter the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH12:MI:SS.FF6 AM';
   ```

   Provided the date language is also correct, then your `INSERT` would work due to the implicit cast using the correct format model. But any user can change their NLS session parameters at any time so you cannot rely on this to be correct.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMuuq6Wn)

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement is fine. The problem is your insert statement, where the format is not correct. We have no idea if that's 1823 vs 2023.

Use this format:

```
insert into my_table (timestamp_column)
values(TIMESTAMP '2023-10-01 09:54:22');

select *
from my_table;
```

Output:

```
01-OCT-23 09.54.22.000000
```

Comment: Oracle assumes the century if it's not specified. It won't think it's 1823. If it's above 50 it will assume 19..., whereas if its under 50 it will assume 20...

Comment: Good to know. No longer use oracle, happily.

Comment: @PaulW Not quite, it depends on the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`. If the format model is `YY` then it assumes the value is in the current century (i.e. `20`); if it is `YYYY` then it assumes the value is in the 1st century AD (i.e. `00`); if it is `RR` then it assumes either previous, current or next century depending on the value and which half of the century we are currently in and which half of the century the value is in (i.e. `19` or `20` at the moment in 27 years, at 2050, it would either be `20` or `21`), see the documentation for the exact rules. You are correct that it will not be `18`.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MIZA8gzC) showing the behaviours of implicit casts with different format models. The moral of the story is to (1) never rely on implicit casts; and (2) always be explicit with the years and specify all the digits.

Comment: @MT0, thanks for the clarification. Nearly everybody showing a two digit year is using YY, so my assumption is normally correct.

Comment: @PaulW Have a look at my answer to [Oracle's Default Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) which describes how the default date format changes around the world. You will find that none of the default date formats are `YY` many of them are `RR` but some are `RRRR` (which behaves the same as `RR` when you only have a 2-digit year). However, your original comment describes the (approximate) behaviour for the `RR` model so you may have just mistyped when you said that "Nearly everybody showing a two digit year is using YY".

Answer (score 1):

Oracle makes no assumptions about date formats. There are many dozens of different ways to represent dates, and unlike other RDBMSs it doesn't attempt to figure out which format you mean. It has to be told. If it isn't, it will use a default, and if it isn't right, you'll get an error. The default is set by the `nls_date_format` parameter (for dates) and `nls_timestamp_format` (for timestamps) at the database level. You can see what it is by querying `v$nls_parameters`, or you can set it yourself at the session level with `alter session set nls_timestamp_format='DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM'`

But far better is to always be explicit about date and timestamp conversions in your code. Always explicitly provide a date format model and explicit `TO_CHAR` and/or `TO_DATE`/`TO_TIMESTAMP` etc..., like this:

```
insert into my_table (timestamp_column) values (TO_TIMESTAMP('14-AUG-23 04.07.50.805201 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM'));
```

Comment: In this case, it is not `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. The OP is using a `TIMESTAMP` column so the NLS parameter that will be used is `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into the_table (the_timestamp_column) values (timestamp '2023-10-17 21:22:23');

One can simply use
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE((the_timestamp_column)
 VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2023-10-17 21:22:23.871+02:00');


This way you won't have to worry about date format string, just use default timestamp format.
```