# how to append time to date without time

Tags: oracle

I have stored column with date format without time `1/15/2020` and I want to concatenate

`12:00:00 AM` time so the column will be `1/15/2020 12:00:00 AM` to that date how ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't feature data types for `DATE` and `TIME`. It  only features datetimes / timestamps. So, despite its name, a `DATE` in Oracle is really a datetime, and storing a date only means to store that date at midnight 00:00:00. Now you want 12 a.m. to get attatched to that date. 12 a.m. is midnight, so there is nothing to do, your stored date 1/15/2020 is already datetime 1/15/2020 12:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7-bytes representing century, year-or-century, month, day, hour minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has all 7 of those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

> how to append time to date without time

You cannot have a date without a time; if it is a `DATE` then it always has a time.

> I have stored column with date format without time `1/15/2020` and I want to concatenate `12:00:00 AM` time so the column will be `1/15/2020 12:00:00 AM` to that date how?

No, you don't. If you have a `DATE` then it is being stored as 7 bytes and has no particular human-readable format (and if you have not explicitly set the time component of the `DATE` then it will default to midnight).

You can see the byte values of the `DATE` using:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(your_date_column) FROM table_name
```

You can change how a single query displays display the `DATE` by converting it to a formatted string using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
         AS your_formatted_date_column
FROM   your_table;
```

Alternatively, you can change the settings for your client application to change how that client displays **all** dates. If your client application is SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLCl then you can alter the [default format used to display dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format/50164234#50164234) by changing the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM';
```

For other client application, check their documentation.

---

If your `DATE` is set with a different time component than midnight and you want to display the time as midnight (`12:00:00 AM`) then use `TRUNC` and one of the previous methods:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(your_date_column), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
         AS your_formatted_date_column
FROM   your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

All dates in Oracle are stored with date and time and in the binary non human readable format.

What you see in the output of the query is nothing but the date formatted by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of the session.

If you have stored date only and haven't used time in that column then it is by default 12AM in the morning. Already truncated.

If you want to see correct time also in the result of the select query just set the NLS parameter as follows:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';
```

Then fire SELECT FROM TABLE query to see what is the actual time saved by oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have a DATE column containing dates truncated to midnight hour, you have just to add an half day:

```
update my_date_col from my_table set my_date_col = my_date_col + 0.5 ;
```

And if you are not sure they are all TRUNCated to midnight you can still:

```
update my_date_col from my_table set my_date_col = trunc(my_date_col) + 0.5 ;
```

Either you have VARCHAR2 column contacting a formatted date and you have to concat the '12:00:00 AM' to it, but storing date as strings is bad idea...

Comment: that is will add PM `1/15/2020 12:00:00 PM` which is the middle of the morning and i want to add the end of the day '1/15/2020 12:00:00 AM'... what i want to insert is the a beginning and the end of day records